# What is the algorithm used by the "Universal Recommender" on Prediction.IO?

Tags: algorithm, prediction

good Afternoon

What is the name algorithm used by the "**Universal Recommender (UR)**" on **Prediction.IO**?

during which i know Algorithm for 
**system recommendation** are "collaborative filtering" and "content based filtering".

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It uses Correlated Cross-Occurrence(CCO) algorithm from Apache-mahout.

check out these
https://actionml.com/blog/cco
https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/recommender-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Prediction.io uses Apache Spark MLLib's Alternating Least Squares matrix factorization method (ALS). It is one of basic methods of Collaborative Filtering, which are User-based, Item-based and Matrix factorization. Documentation can be found at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html

Universal Recommender Template use this algorithm for computing "events" that are appearing "often" with "buying" some "item". Use of factorization is not what authors of Universal Recommender principle describe in their original idea, instead they used LLR similarity to find statistically significant "events". I personally doubt about suitability of use of matrix factorization and use of HBase (use Redis cluster instead). You can read about Universal Recommender general idea at https://www.mapr.com/practical-machine-learning and http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/recommender-overview.html

Comment: this answer seems to be inprecise; there are several templates for prediction.io, some which either use the ALS matrix factorization approach OR the UR-template which does not use ALS at all; rather, it is build on co-occurences based on correlated co-occurences which is a rather different operation compared to the ALS approach. ALS leverages latent factores, which means compressing the sparse user-item matrix to low-rank matrices, and UR leverages the log-likelihood ratio statistics to find confidence between different pairs of events (like view, interact, purchase, etc.)